# What is the original source for the quote: "We were commanded to strike with the sword whoever opposes the Book of Allah.''?

Tags: tafseer

On 2 english language tafsir websites there is a quote attributed to Jabir included in the english of the Ibn-Kathir commentary for Quran 29:46.  The arabic corresponding to the comments do not include the quote attributed to Jabir.  The arabic provided is a Quran quote from 57:25.

Is the quote attributed to Jabir in the english authentic?
If so what is the original source?

Is the quote attributed to Jabir actually included in the Ibn-Kathir tafsir?  Was it added by the publishers of these websites?

Thank you,

https://www.alim.org/quran/tafsir/ibn-kathir/surah/29/46/
[image: Text]

https://quranx.com/tafsirs/29.46
[image: Text]

Comment: This report seems to originally come from Tarikh Dimashq [here](https://app.turath.io/book/71?page=24206).

Comment: Thank you very much @TheZ